# Getting ORA-29269 error while calling utl_http.begin_request

Tags: oracle, http

I have been trying to send request to a Web Service by issuing UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST, but I get the error "ORA-29269: HTTP server error 500 - Server Error" if I call it like this:

```
v_request_pri := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(v_ws_url_pri, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
```

where `v_ws_url_pri` is the URL of the web service.

What surprises is, when I call `UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST` with only the URL as the parameter (in which case, the second parameter is the 'GET' method by default, and the HTTP version is checked as latest), there is no error and the call is through.

Please if somebody may guide on the error, it would be a great help to me.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: If the server is returning that, shouldn't you be asking the provider of the web service why? Maybe they don't accept POST requests at all, or maybe they're getting an error they need to investigate from their logs?

Comment: Thanks Alex for the insight, will be contacting the provider. Will be posting the same here after they respond. Thanks again..

Comment: I highly doubt the problem is utl_htp/oracle side. If a 500 is returned, then there is something wrong with your server. 500 refer to internal server error.